# WildFly 10: @Stateful.name property is ignored

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-10

I'm trying to put up an EJB Container on JBoss Wildfly on my local machine, and I, with some help, managed to get the container up and running, with the Remote EJB beans recognized. However, I'd like them to be named differently.

I have a NAME property in all interfaces with the desired name of the implementing bean. I put that string in the `@Stateless(name = Interface.NAME)`.

However, the bean still gets created with the implementing class name.
What should I do?

Edit: My EJB Implementation:

```
@Stateful(mappedName = StateService.NAME)
public class StateServiceImpl implements StateService {

private final Map<SessionId, Deque<State>> sessions;
private final List<StateChangeListener> listeners;

public StateServiceImpl() {
    this.sessions = new HashMap<>();
    this.listeners = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public State getCurrentState(SessionId sessionId) {
    return sessions.get(sessionId).peek();
}

@Override
public State popCurrentState(SessionId sessionId) {
    State previousState = sessions.get(sessionId).pop();
    State currentState = sessions.get(sessionId).peek();

    StateChangeEvent event = new StateChangeEvent(previousState, currentState);
    fireStateChangeEvent(event);

    return currentState;
}

@Override
public Deque<State> getStateHistory(SessionId sessionId) {
    return new LinkedList<>(sessions.get(sessionId));
}

@Override
public void updateState(SessionId sessionId, State state) {
    State previousState = sessions.get(sessionId).peek();

    if (!sessions.containsKey(sessionId)) {
        sessions.put(sessionId, new LinkedList<>());
    }

    sessions.get(sessionId).push(state);

    StateChangeEvent event = new StateChangeEvent(previousState, state);
    fireStateChangeEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void addStateChangeListener(StateChangeListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public void removeStateChangeListener(StateChangeListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

protected void fireStateChangeEvent(StateChangeEvent event) {
    listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.stateChanged(event));
}
}
```

My Interface:

```
/**
 * Service interface to manage state changes on the server-side
 */
@Remote
public interface StateService {

    String NAME = "StateService";

    /**
     * returns the most recent state stored for the given session id
     */
    State getCurrentState(SessionId sessionId);

    /**
     * removes the last entry of session from the queue, returning the one before
     */
    State popCurrentState(SessionId sessionId);

    /**
     * returns the whole history of a given client
     */
    Deque<State> getStateHistory(SessionId sessionId);

    /**
     * adds a new session to the stack
     *
     * @param sessionId the client the state is updated for
     * @param state     the updated state
     */
    void updateState(SessionId sessionId, State state);

    void addStateChangeListener(StateChangeListener listener);

    void removeStateChangeListener(StateChangeListener listener);

    interface StateChangeListener {
        void stateChanged(StateChangeEvent event);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    class StateChangeEvent {
        private final State previousState;
        private final State nextState;
    }
}
```

These are the bindings:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:global/web-be/web-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MenuServiceImpl!io.ropi.fiveshelly.services.MenuService
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:app/web-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MenuServiceImpl!io.ropi.fiveshelly.services.MenuService
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:module/MenuServiceImpl!io.ropi.fiveshelly.services.MenuService
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:global/web-be/web-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MenuServiceImpl
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:app/web-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MenuServiceImpl
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   java:module/MenuServiceImpl
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: including the `@RemoteBinding()` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can change the name of the class itself, but as an example you can use the name of the published JNDI (Depends is my project's name):

```
java:global/Depends/NameDesired!MyClassName
java:app/Depends/NameDesired!MyClassName
java:module/NameDesired!MyClassName
java:global/Depends/NameDesired
java:app/Depends/NameDesired
java:module/NameDesired
```

The class is this:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name="NameDesired")
public class MyClassName { 
    public void doThing() {
        System.out.println("Doing some work...");
    }
}
```

Then you can use like:

```
//I'm using here the fourth line of the JNDI, just using the name I want:
MyClassName example = (MyClassName) (new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/Depends/NameDesired"));
```

or even

```
@EJB(beanName="NameDesired")
private MyClassName example;
```

Note that you are using the correct annotation already @Stateless(name=""). As we talked in chat, you can set the name you want using a String. Even more you can lookup using [Environment Variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/servjndi014.htm#CIABGEFE) and how to [Configure it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/servjndi008.htm), but in your case, I don't know if worth it.

Comment: That's exactly what's not working. I have my class annotated the already, tried name, and mappedName even. But my JNDI name still looks like `java:global/Depends/ImplementationClassName!package.InterfaceClassName`

Comment: Can you post all your wildfly JNDI bindings please?

Comment: Ok, now I have you class. I would like to see the JNDIs that are being published when you start wildfly. It looks like what I first posted. It's after "JNDI bindings for session bean named <MyClass>"...

Comment: yee I'm a scrub, sorry :D

Comment: Ok, I runned your project here. I don't know if that's exactly what you need but I got "java:global/Depends/StateService.NAME" Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182380/discussion-between-jhenrique-and-laszlo-stahorszki).

Comment: it's definitely "better" result then mine is, however, I'd more like to have the string stored in StateService.Name (which actually is "StateService")